# Does a melody (which will be used with chords) need to have the notes in the same scale?

Tags: chords, harmony, melody

I am trying to play a melody (that I got from a book) from piano to guitar and add chords to fingerstyle.

Edit: I'd like to know if I need to play the notes of a melody at the positions from a specific scale on the guitar. Or If I can play the same each musical notes but in different scale/positions

For Example: the melody starts with B and then goes to A#. Ok, then I look to the guitar and see many Bs and many A#s on that instrument. Now, I can play this sequence in different "structures"/scales or is needed follow the order of some scale (of the first note position played), example scale of Bm

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's very difficult to understand exactly what you need to know from your question.Please add some more information so we can help better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that most of the notes that can be played on the guitar can be played in more than one place, and there are many different ways to play the same scale - and yes, you can play the scale in any shape or position that you like.

Of course just because you see many 'B's doesn't mean that they're all the same note - some of them will be an octave apart. But they can all still be used in any scale that contains a 'B'!

Comment: Another point is that when you play the same note on a different string there is a slight difference in the quality of the sound. (Overtones and such) so that a drastic switch to the same note on a different string can be seen as either jarring or a neat effect depending on the circumstance, guitar and taste.